# NSMutableURLRequest on succession of another NSMutableURLRequest's success

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Basically, I want to implement SYNC functionality; where, if internet connection is not available, data gets stored on local sqlite database. Whenever, internet connection is available, SYNC gets into the action.

Now, Say for example; 5 records are stored locally, and then internet connection is available. I want the server to be updated. So, What I do currently is:

1. Post first record to the server.
2. Wait for the success of first request.
3. Post local NSNotification to routine, that the first record has been updated on server & now second request can go.
4. The routine fires the second post request on server and so on...

Question: Is this approach right and efficient enough to implement SYNC functionality; OR anything I should change into it ??

**NOTE: Records to be SYNC will have no limit in numbers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on the requirements on the data that you save. If it is just for backup then you should be fine. 
If the 5 records are somehow dependent on each other and you need to access this data from another device/application you should take care on the server side that either all 5 records are written or none. Otherwise you will have an inconsistent state if only 3 get written.
If other users are also reading / writing those data concurrently on the server then you need to implement some kind of lock on all records before writing and also decide how to handle conflicts when someone attempts to overwrite somebody else changes.

Comment: You mean Atomicity and Concurrency, right. Got Your Point, Sir.

Comment: Sorry about being overlong in the answer, I did not know if you knew those concepts ;-) Glad I could help.